Alice in Wonderland/Through the Looking Glass: What are the best commentaries that have been written about them?
I have recently become more aware of the significance of Lewis Carrol's two most well-known works of fiction, particularly in terms of how they relate to the philosophy of language. I think that he points out some very deep issues related to how language functions. So, I was wondering if there were any particularly noteworthy commentaries on those books. (Of course, I could do a Google search, but I just want to know if there are any rather well-known analyses that I might overlook, given that literature is not my area of expertise.)

My favorite books! I'd start with: The Annotated Alice (the 1960 and 1990 versions). It explains a lot of the arcana. Have fun! And don't forget "The Hunting of the Snark".

Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Unfortunately questions asking for recommendations or an open-ended list are off-topic for the site.  You could edit to cite a specific passage from the book, then ask what its implications are for philosophy of language. The answers would probably cite works you could then look up. Thanks!

Or you could ask this question in chat.

I highly recommend Martin Gardner's The Annotated Alice. But, as verbose noted, this question is off-topic for Literature SE due to being too open-ended and opinion-based. Feel free to start a discussion in chat where some literature-knowledgeable people hang out for more informal discussion.
